# How to get notifications in an office add-ins when the Time or TO list changes

Tags: outlook-web-addins

Is there a way to get notifications in your Add-In that something has changed in Outlook?

Setting or reading properties is not a problem, but I need to know when they add/remove someone to/from the "To", "cc" or "bcc" list, or when they change the start or end date.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the easiest way to do this is with setTimeout, something along the lines of:

```
var ToTimeout = 5000; // 5 seconds
var currentTo;

function onToChange() { /* your code here */ }

function checkTo() {
    Office.context.mailbox.item.to.getAsync(function (result) {
        if(result.error) { /* handle error */);
        if(result.value != currentTo) {
            currentTo = result.value;
            onToChange();
        }
    });
    setTimeout(checkTo, ToTimeout);
}

setTimeout(checkTo, ToTimout);
```

There is a request on UserVoice to add an api for watching for these changes [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/10315167-provide-an-event-to-let-outlook-add-in-respond-to). Please upvote if you want this feature.